# Write a shell script to telnet a http webstie?

Tags: http, shell, telnet

I can telnet a HTTP website in terminal like

```
$telnet 111.111.111.111 2222
Trying 111.111.111.111...
Connected to 111.111.111.111.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Then I can type:

```
GET /url/page.php HTTP/1.1"
HOST: 111.111.111.111
```

After typing Enter twice, I can get the page.
Does anyone know how to do this using a shell script？
I want to get the same result as using the commands above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a program like `wget` or `curl` to download Web pages; those take care of the protocol details for you.  If you absolutely must directly send the characters, look at the `nc` command; you might need to script it with `expect`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes I need to send the protocol request, but it doesn't matter to use telnet or nc. Could you give me an example for doing this with either telnet or nc?

Comment: @Chris: Are you sending valid HTTP requests?  A real HTTP program will do the job much more easily than writing it by hand.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642707/problem-scripting-a-html-header-request-with-netcat for `nc` directions, though.

Comment: Actually not. I need to play with the protocol. Thanks for the link. I tried to put the http protocol into a separate file and redirect it to `nc` with `i` flag and this works. When I using pipeline, I noticed that `printf"request1\nrequest2\r\n\r\n" | nc...`works but if I use `\r\n` in the middle of the 2 requests, it will just return the header. Any ideas on the difference between `\n` and `\r\n`?

Comment: It looks no one is looking at this question any more...Any way, thanks for your help.