# Make SOAP call in bash without curl or wget

Tags: bash, soap

I am trying to write a bash script to execute a SOAP request(and get response). which I can do with

```
result=$(wget ${url} --post-data="${data}" --header='Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8'--timeout=${timeout} -qO- --delete-after)
```

or

```
result=$(curl --silent --header 'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8' --data "${data}" "${url}" --connect-timeout "${timeout}")
```

where 'data' is the XML payload.

However the server I need to execute the script from does not have curl or wget, and likely not any other such extended features.

So is there a way to achieve this without using them?
A related stackexhange question suggests it might be possible, although their requirement is slightly different.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83926/how-to-download-a-file-using-just-bash-and-nothing-else-no-curl-wget-perl-et

Thanks

EDIT :
Following Nic3500 comment, I have spent all day reading up on nc/netcat and struggling to find the docs i need. But I have got it to send the following:

```
POST <remote_URI> HTTP/1.1\r\n
User-Agent: Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Host: <IP Address>\r\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8--timeout=10\r\n
Content-Length: <Content Length>\r\n
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="Core" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:Dispatch>
      <param0 xsi:type="xsd:string">some data</param0>
      [more params here]
      <param21 xsi:type="xsd:int">1</param21>
    </ns1:Dispatch>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

using

```
echo ${head} | nc <IP Address> 80
```

Now as far as i can tell that precisely matches what the wget method sends(which works, just not executable from the server i need) based on getting that to dump the data it sends.
However clearly something isn't quite right, because all i get back is a 400 Bad request.

Comment: Do you have more "evolved" scripting languages installed on the server?  i.e. perl, python, php, ...?  These have better extensions you can use than pure bash.

Comment: @Nic3500 Sadly no perl python or php.

Comment: They like to make your life hell I see ;-)  Look at this maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850271/linux-script-telnet-head-request  `netcat` or `nc` might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I wasn't far off on the attempt I made with the edit, Just needed the -e switch on the echo command :

```
POST <remote_URI> HTTP/1.1\r\n
User-Agent: Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Host: <IP Address>\r\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8--timeout=10\r\n
Content-Length: <Content Length>\r\n
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="Core" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:Dispatch>
      <param0 xsi:type="xsd:string">some data</param0>
      [more params here]
      <param21 xsi:type="xsd:int">1</param21>
    </ns1:Dispatch>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

By assigning this to the data variable, then running :

```
result=$(echo -e "${data}" | nc -w ${timeout} ${url} 80)
```

Resolved the issue I was having, as -e tells echo to interpret the line breaks, and all the issues I was having using nc were actually down to incorrect line endings in some shapre or form. For reference - as seen above - HTTP data needs CRLF line endings.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this command where data is the SOAP-ENV xml. Output will be pretty formatted xml response from webservice.

```
wget --read-timeout=30 --no-cache --no-check-certificate \
--header='Content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8' \
--post-data='${data}' \
-O - ${url} | xmllint --format -
```