# Make a (CURL-like) HTTP request without the "Http version" for testing?

Tags: bash, unix, curl

I'm testing malformed HTTP requests on OSX, but I can't workout how to make a request with a missing/malformed http version.

Curl seems to only allow [valid presets](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) (--http1.0, --http1.1, --http1)

*Whats the easiest way to construct a request without "http version"?*

### Example:

Given the following commands create the following request lines:

#### Ex1.

command: `curl -i http://localhost:8080/cat.jpg?v=1`

request: `GET cat.jpg?v=1 HTTP/1.1`

#### Ex2.

command: `curl -i http://localhost:8080/cat.jpg?v=1 --http1.0`

request: `GET cat.jpg?v=1 HTTP/1.0`

#### Wanted

How could I create the following

command: `???`

request: `GET cat.jpg?v=1` (*missing http version*)

#### EDIT: ANSWER

*curl* only deals with valid requests. *netcat* is an alternative that has more control.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642707/scripting-an-http-header-request-with-netcat)

Thanks @DanFromGermany

Comment: Please show an example of what you mean. Are you saying you want to test protocols exist? Obviously curl can not use a protocol it doesn't know about, nothing can.

Comment: Do you understand how http works? How do you expect to get the webpage without http?

Comment: I'm writing a http/file server, and I want to test what happens if the request that is received is malformed

Comment: You can't have a missing http verison. You have to have some protocol in place in order to communicate with the server.

Comment: Curl is not a pentesting tool. Don't use curl. Use netcat or perl or PHP or whatever allows you to send data through a socket. But don't use a tool that is supposed to send only valid data.

Comment: @123 You don't understand the question. He wants to send WRONG data ON PURPOSE to test how his webserver would react.

Comment: Ahhh, yeah perhaps i should of rephrased the question as a "recommend me a tool...."

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic on Stackoverflow. You would go on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @DanFromGermany ah right, If you just want to send data to a port use `nc`.

Comment: Use these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642707/scripting-an-http-header-request-with-netcat

Comment: Ok.  I'm loathe to remove this question though, as for someone who doesn't know CURLs limitations - its hard to workout that you need an alternative tool. I'll leave it up to the mods.